# How to multiply all array element at once without iteration in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array consisting of more than 25k elements. All array values are integer. NOw i want to multiply all elements of this array by some number "n".... how can I do that with out iterating thru each element using a i.e. without using a foreach?

I am looking for this bcoz iterating thru such large array might affect the performance ...

Deepak

Comment: You are going to have to iterate over the array somehow. Even something like `array_map()` (see answers using it below) causes PHP to iterate over the array internally.

Answer (score 1):

```
function multiplyElements( $inElem ){
  return $inElem * n; // Where "n" is the number to multiply all elements by
}

$yourArray = array_map( 'multiplyElements' , $yourArray );
```

Comment: Though there shouldn't be any performance gain - this answer at-least sticks to the point and answers what the OP asked :)

Comment: @JP19 Though it *is* with iteration, just implicit.

Answer (score 1):

*"might affect the performance"* is not a valid reason to optimize. Make sure it *does* affect performance. If you are sure it negatively affects performance, consider using one of the Spl Data Structures

- http://de.php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php
- http://matthewturland.com/2010/05/20/new-spl-features-in-php-5-3/

This would still leave you iterating, but for large datasets, those datastructures can make a difference in both execution speed and memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `array_sum()`, but not array multiplier function.

You will need to iterate (or use `array_map()`, which just abstracts the iteration from you).

I would also make sure your number doesn't overflow PHP's max integer size (check `PHP_INT_MAX` on your platform). You may need to use [`gcmul()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php).

Comment: Just my two cents: Given that the question itself is slightly silly, and I don't understand what value the "overflow" comment add - thats true for any multiplication operation in PHP and is nothing specific to this question.

Comment: @JP19 I read it as `How to multiply all array elements [together]`, which he noted there were 25k - that *could* indeed become a large number.

Comment: Oh sorry. Then my comment is really not valid and your answer is indeed useful. I doubt he meant multiple 25K numbers together though, especially since he talks about 'n'

Answer (score 0):

Well because of bunch of deleted answers, which were *right* ones.

1. You are going to have to iterate over the array somehow. Even using something like array_map() (see other two answers) causes PHP to iterate over the array internally.
2. **The best** way to optimize 25k iterations is to **avoid** such large numbers at all. **Or** at least place it in the background where performance wouldn't be significant.
3. If you came to that point anyway, the fastest way is a matter of test. it seems aaray_map is worst one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Nested function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function) like below

```
function arrayFunc($e){
    if(is_array($e)) return array_map('arrayFunc', $e);
    else return $e; // Set your changes here for example change this line to : else return $e * 1000;
}
$array = arrayFunc($array);
```